# Pavlova Roll failure

Tags: consistency

Why did the meringue in my pavlova roll turn out rubbery in consistency.
Was it baked for too long. It was baked  at 170 deg for 10 min then at 150 deg for an hour. then switched off the oven and let cool in the oven

**Update**
The temp was Celsius I had the fan on also. it was baked as a flat rectangle on a tray and then rolled. Today I made another one and it was a lot better,not rubbery and I only baked it for 30 mins.

Comment: Do you mean Fahrenheit or Celsius? A more complete recipe would be helpful too. Are you baking in a sheet pan and then rolling? Or are you baking a log shape?

Answer (score 1):

170°C, 150°C?  That is just too hot.

Snow-white crisp merignue process is more of drying, not actually baking.  Which is why the temperature must be in 100-120°C.  Also, forced air circulation must be turned off.

Comment: I'm sure the OP meant Fahrenheit.

Comment: @Jolenealaska You think? My oven doesn't go that low.

Comment: Well actually, now I don't know. I looked at several recipes, and some do call for a very low oven (180F) for an hour, but now I see recipes that do call for 350F for 10 minutes. At any rate, if it is Celsius, I'm not finding any recipes that are for that hot, for that long. It's 10 minutes, and then done at 350F or one hour at 180F.

Comment: @Jefromi The closest I can find is Ina Garten's. Hers is 180F for 1.5 hours, turn off oven, cool completely in oven. I also see several for 10 minutes at 350F, remove from oven immediately.